# Need past 2 results from observable as input into a third

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Is there a way to get the past 2 results from an observable sequence and use as input into a third.

Here is the code without any observables.

```
public login(...): Promise<any> {
    const user: any = ctx.prisma.query.user({ where: { email } });
    if (!user) {
        throw new Error(`No such user found for email: ${email}`);
    }

    const valid = bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!valid) {
        throw new Error("Invalid password");
    }

    return {
        token: jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.APP_SECRET),
        user,
    };
}
```

---

Here is my solution that does not work that brought me to ask this question. This doesn't work because i do not have the `user` result from the call to `ctx.prisma.query.user(...)` when i need to check `valid` and do my `map`.

```
public login(...): Promise<any> {
    return from(ctx.prisma.query.user({ where: { email } })).pipe(
        mergeMap(
            (user: User) => {
                if (!user) {
                    throw new Error(`No such user found for email: ${email}`);
                }
                return from(bcrypt.compare(password, user.password));
            }
        ),
        map(
            (valid: boolean) => {
                if (!valid) {
                    throw new Error("Invalid password");
                }

                return {
                    token: jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.APP_SECRET),
                    user,
                };
            }
        )
    ).toPromise();
}
```

---

Here is my attempt at this solution that works, but i was just wondering if this is correct or if there is a better way.

I need the `user` and the `valid` result in my `map` so that i can create the correct object.

My solution just feels weird, because if i needed to keep going with this sequence and previous results it would get really deep.

```
public login(...): Promise<any> {
    return from(ctx.prisma.query.user({ where: { email } })).pipe(
        switchMap(
            (user: User) => {
                if (!user) {
                    throw new Error(`No such user found for email: ${email}`);
                }
                return from(bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)).pipe(
                    map(
                        (valid: boolean) => {
                            if (!valid) {
                                throw new Error("Invalid password");
                            }

                            return {
                                token: jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.APP_SECRET),
                                user,
                            };
                        }
                    )
                );
            }
        )
    ).toPromise();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @bryan60 and @Daniel Gimenez, we came to the conclusion that my provided solution in my question is the most accurate with version 6. Here is my final solution.

```
public login(
    source: any, 
    {email, password}, 
    ctx: IContext, 
    info: GraphQLResolveInfo): Promise<any> {

    return from(ctx.prisma.query.user({ where: { email } })).pipe(
        tap(
            (user: User) => {
                if (!user) {
                    throw new Error(`No such user found for email: ${email}`);
                }
            }
        ),
        switchMap(
            (user: User) => {
                return from(bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)).pipe(
                    map(
                        (valid: boolean) => {
                            if (!valid) {
                                throw new Error("Invalid password");
                            }

                            return {
                                token: jwt.sign(
                                    { userId: user.id }, 
                                    process.env.APP_SECRET
                                ),
                                user,
                            };
                        }
                    )
                );
            }
        )
    ).toPromise();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

switchMap is the operator you want, the second argument to switchMap is a map function that takes the result of both the inner and outer observable and lets you combine them as such (mergemap accepts the same second argument, but switchMap is preferred due to it being the "safer" operator):

```
public login(...): Promise<any> {
    return from(ctx.prisma.query.user({ where: { email } })).pipe(
        switchMap(
            (user: User) => {
                if (!user) {
                    throw new Error(`No such user found for email: ${email}`);
                }
                return from(bcrypt.compare(password, user.password));
            }
        , (user, valid) => {
            if (!valid) {
                throw new Error("Invalid password");
            }

            return {
                token: jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.APP_SECRET),
                user,
            };
        }
    )).toPromise();
}
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when trying this code. `Argument of type '(user: any, valid: any) => { token: any, user: any }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<any, any>'`. I am working through it right now, just wondering if you have any insight.

Comment: I figured it out. Your parenthesis are not correct. I will edit your answer to correct it.

Comment: The documentation is saying this use of `switchmap` is deprecated. Looking into `inner map` now.

Comment: my bad on the parens, thanks for the catch.  I'm looking at the rxjs docs, i dont see a deprecation notice? Have a link? They're changing too much on every single release to keep up with anymore.  The library is so useful and powerful but they negate it with the constant breaking changes.

Comment: Here is the migration doc from version 5 to 6. It says that `resultselectors` are deprecated. In most situations it seems like an `inner map` should be used instead. I am trying to convert what i have to that. But it seems like it would be similar to the solution that i posted in my question. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: That is extremely annoying. Thank you for the heads up on this, but yea, it looks like the function you've already implemented is the recommended path now.  I'd love to hear why they deprecated one of their most useful features. Anyway, I'm gona have to now go rewrite half of my observable streams if I want any hope of migrating to future versions of Angular.

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple of things in your solution you could do to avoid all the levels of nesting, but IMO there's nothing wrong about what you have.

The first change I do is to use `tap` for the error checking.  This is really only for appearances sake, though I guess checking for errors in a map feels wrong.

Next the `switchMap` is changed to take a `forkJoin` that combines the retrieved user value, and the result of the decryption.  The `forkJoin` was the cleanest way I could think of to pass the user further along in the sequence.

The rest is pretty straight forward.

```
from(ctx.prisma.query.user({ where: { email } })).pipe(
    tap(user => { if (!user) throw new Error(`No such user found for email: ${email}`); }),
    switchMap(user => forkJoin(of(user), from(bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))),
    tap(([user, valid]) => { if (!valid) throw new Error('Invalid password'); })
    map(([user, valid]) => ({
        token: jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.APP_SECRET),
        user,
    }))
)
```

Comment: switchMap accepts a second argument that is a map function to combine the values of both inner and outer, no need to add the forkjoin

Comment: I never knew that until I saw your answer.

Comment: I did not either.

Comment: it's very useful, i agree that taps to error catch are the cleaner error handling approach

Comment: Yeah, but @bryan60, your answer had the secret sauce in it.  I would accept yours

Comment: @DanielGimenez I will probably be accepting @bryan60's. I am just testing it and working through the documentation for `switchmap` right now. Because i never noticed the inner and outer stuff on the `switchmap` before.